# cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract static class ApplicationC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

I make a project using dagger hilt and when I make a dynamic feature it shows an error like this

```
    /MyApplication_HiltComponents.java:166: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.apps.jobwishlist3.core.domain.usecase.JobUseCase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class ApplicationC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.apps.jobwishlist3.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC
      com.apps.jobwishlist3.core.domain.usecase.JobUseCase is requested at
          com.apps.jobwishlist3.di.FullTimeModuleDependencies.jobUseCase()
```

I don't really know what the error means. I tried to erased @singeton and still, that error comes.

I already make everything it need for dagger hilt like this code

```
    @EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface FullTimeModuleDependencies {

    fun jobUseCase(): JobUseCase
}
```

and this

```
    @Component(dependencies = [FullTimeModuleDependencies::class])
interface FullTimeComponent {

    fun inject(activity: FullTimeActivity)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun context(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder
        fun appDependencies(fullTimeModuleDependencies: FullTimeModuleDependencies): Builder
        fun build(): FullTimeComponent
    }

}
```

but still dagger doesn't generate it in my this activity code

```
DaggerFullTimeComponent.builder()
        .context(this)
        .appDependencies(
            EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                applicationContext,
                FullTimeModuleDependencies::class.java
            )
        )
        .build()
        .inject(this)
```

the `DaggerFullTimeComponent` still red and I don't know what to do. please help if there someone know. Thank you.

this is my full project if you need to know the whole thing: https://github.com/cube76/JobWishlist3

Answer (score 0):

From your project, `JobUseCase` is the interface and dagger does not know how to provide him. Probably you have to add the binds method for your implementation of the `JobUseCase` into any dagger module.

```
@Binds 
fun bindJobUseCase(interactor: JobInteractor): JobUseCase
```

Comment: I put that in `FullTimeComponent` and the error still the same. did you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error text:

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.apps.jobwishlist3.core.domain.usecase.JobUseCase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

and

> A binding with matching key exists in component: `com.apps.jobwishlist3.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC`

We can determine that Dagger knows how to find your JobUseCase in your *Activity* component, but not your *Application* component. We can confirm that [as a mistake in your linked repo](https://github.com/cube76/JobWishlist3/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/apps/jobwishlist3/di/AppModule.kt#L10-L17):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class) // ActivityComponent installation
                                     // but named AppModule
abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun provideJobUseCase(jobInteractor: JobInteractor): JobUseCase

}
```

Changing `ActivityComponent` to `ApplicationComponent` (as it appears in [DatabaseModule](https://github.com/cube76/JobWishlist3/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/apps/jobwishlist3/core/di/DatabaseModule.kt#L15)) will allow your ApplicationComponent and its FullTimeModuleDependencies to resolve from `EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication`, solving your problem.